# How to change the cursor on hover in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I managed to add interactivity to a feature layer added from a remote GeoJSON resource. When I click on a feature I get its ID, fire an AJAX request and display some relevant info about the feature, on the page outside of the map area.

I used a `Select` interaction.

I would like to make it even clearer to the user that he can click on the features on the map. Is there any way I can change the mouse cursor to "cursor" of "hand" when the mouse hovers a feature contained in a `ol.layer.Vector` ?

I couldn't find anything in the doc, on this site or by googling.

Comment: There is an example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/icon.html. To be honest I'm trying to use the same method in my map but without success: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cursor' of undefined**

Comment: @Azathoth `getTarget` gives you what to give to the map target: either string or HTMLElement. Should be HTMLElement, like in the example, if you want to change its style.

Comment: @tonio I think I copied all the code usend in the example but 
**console.log(map.getTarget());** prints a string containing "map"

Comment: @Azathoth : see my answer on how to deal with the string value you get

Comment: `map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';` worked for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be done as well without jQuery:

```
map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
    var hit = this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return true;
    }); 
    if (hit) {
        this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: In 3.17.1 this code works.  But not with this.getTarget(), use this.getTargetElement()

Answer (score 20):

Here is another way to do it:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e){
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
  map.getViewport().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

Comment: Side note, you should add the missing paren ");" at the end for easy copy pasting

Answer (score 13):

If that doesn't work, try a combination of the 2, seemed to work for my vector popup...

```
var target = map.getTarget();
var jTarget = typeof target === "string" ? $("#" + target) : $(target);
// change mouse cursor when over marker
$(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
    var hit = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        return true;
    });
    if (hit) {
        jTarget.css("cursor", "pointer");
    } else {
        jTarget.css("cursor", "");
    }
});
```

Comment: this one works for me, the others don't.
OL3 // Version: v3.1.0-pre.2-179-gca3dfe2

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the example link provided by Azathoth in the comments I worked a solution out:

- using OL3 `pointermove` event
- using jQuery to get the target element and change its cursor style

Here is the code :

```
var cursorHoverStyle = "pointer";
var target = map.getTarget();

//target returned might be the DOM element or the ID of this element dependeing on how the map was initialized
//either way get a jQuery object for it
var jTarget = typeof target === "string" ? $("#"+target) : $(target);

map.on("pointermove", function (event) {
    var mouseCoordInMapPixels = [event.originalEvent.offsetX, event.originalEvent.offsetY];

    //detect feature at mouse coords
    var hit = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(mouseCoordInMapPixels, function (feature, layer) {
        return true;
    });

    if (hit) {
        jTarget.css("cursor", cursorHoverStyle);
    } else {
        jTarget.css("cursor", "");
    }
});
```

Here is the link to the example on OpenLayers site : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/icon.html

Answer (score 4):

Another way (combined from parts of above answers, but even simpler):

```
map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
    var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel);
    map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = (hit ? 'pointer' : '');
});
```

Comment: This is the correct way to fo it with OpenLayers 5.

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked like this:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
          if (e.dragging) return;
          var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
          var hit = e.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {
              return true;
          });
          e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
        });
```

I also added a layer filter:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
      if (e.dragging) return;
      var pixel = e.map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
      var hit = e.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature, layer) {
          return layer.get('name') === 'myLayer';
      });
      e.map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
    });
```

I had to select a new solution as the old one I had use for the layer filter before did not work anymore:

```
var hit = e.map.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(layer){
             return layer.get('name') === 'myLayer';
          });
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but don't forget to mention that a layer has no native 'name' attribution, and this has to be set (here, on layer creation).


         `var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: mySource,
            style: myStyle,
            name: "myLayerName"
        });`

Answer (score 2):

I did it with the following code:

```
var target = $(map.getTargetElement()); //getTargetElement is experimental as of 01.10.2015
map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
    if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel)) { //hasFeatureAtPixel is experimental as of 01.10.2015
        target.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    } else {
        target.css('cursor', '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cursor' of undefined.`

Fixed with: `map.getTargetElement()s.style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';` instead of `map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to get target element

```
var target = map.getTarget();

target = typeof target === "string" ?
    document.getElementById(target) : target;

target.style.cursor = features.length > 0) ? 'pointer' : '';
```

Comment: Reason for downvote: use map.getTargetElement() (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getTargetElement).

Answer (score 1):

If you guys are using Angular 2 you must use the following code:

```
this.map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
    var hit = evt.map.hasFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel);
    this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});
```

If the map variable is a member class you refer to it as "this.map", instead if it is declared inside the current function it can be refered to as "map". But above all, you don't write

```
map.getTargetElement()
```

but you write

```
this.getTargetElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

I *tried* to minimize `pointermove` event closure, by avoiding to update style when not necessary, because it calls so very often:

Example-1: uses **jQuery**:

```
var cursorStyle = "";
map.on("pointermove", function (e) {
    let newStyle = this.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel) ? "pointer" : "";
    newStyle !== cursorStyle && $(this.getTargetElement()).css("cursor", cursorStyle = newStyle);
});
```

Example-2: **no** jQuery:

```
var cursorStyle = "";
map.on("pointermove", function (e) {
    let newStyle = this.hasFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel) ? "pointer" : "";
    if (newStyle !== cursorStyle) {
        this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = cursorStyle = newStyle;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way

```
map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
      const pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
      const hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
      document.getElementById('map').style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
    });
}
```